# Error: Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting below error when executing my application. It says to create a bean of type HttpSecurity, "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration"

Please let me know if I need to provide any other details.

error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method managementSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.deprem-ping</groupId>
    <artifactId>deprem-ping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>deprem-ping</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jersey.version>3.0.0-M6</jersey.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                            </additionalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.depremping.depremping.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${principalRequestHeader:X-API-Key}")
    private String principalRequestHeader;

    @Value("${principalRequestValue:109353c6-6432-4acf-8e77-ef842f64a664}")
    private String principalRequestValue;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ApiKeyAuthFilter filter = new ApiKeyAuthFilter(principalRequestHeader);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(
                authentication -> {
                    String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    if (!Objects.equals(principalRequestValue, principal)) {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException(
                                "The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
                    }
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                    return authentication;
                });
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(filter)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/**")
                        .authenticated()
                );


        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I tried to fix the details in the error and then I tried to use this method instead of requestMatchers

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/**")
                        .authenticated()
                );
```

Comment: I would start by removing the `jakarta.servlet-api`, `akarta.persistence-api` and `spring-data-jpa` dependencies. Those are already pulled in by their respective starters (`spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, the latter you would need to add) leaving them in will hurt you when you start to upgrade. Also the `spring-test` dependency isn't needed, already pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-test`. That might not solve it so could you add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.the problem is that when I deleted the @Autowired anatation in my userService file, my application started working